# How can I convert *.vert & *.frag to char in C?

Tags: android, c, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm writing a OpenGL with NDK example.

My shader code in *main.c*:

```
const char vShaderStr[] =
      "#version 300 es                             \n"
      "uniform mat4 u_mvpMatrix;                   \n"
      "layout(location = 0) in vec4 a_position;    \n"
      "layout(location = 1) in vec4 a_color;       \n"
      "out vec4 v_color;                           \n"
      "void main()                                 \n"
      "{                                           \n"
      "   v_color = a_color;                       \n"
      "   gl_Position = u_mvpMatrix * a_position;  \n"
      "}                                           \n";

const char fShaderStr[] =
      "#version 300 es                                \n"
      "precision mediump float;                       \n"
      "in vec4 v_color;                               \n"
      "layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;        \n"
      "void main()                                    \n"
      "{                                              \n"
      "  outColor = v_color;                          \n"
      "}                                              \n";

userData->programObject = esLoadProgram ( vShaderStr, fShaderStr );
```

I had tried this [snippet](https://github.com/joshb/glsl_lighting/blob/master/shader.c) to convert(I also change the way of create shader in *main.c*), but failed:

I want use extern shader file by reading them in *main.c*  .

How can I convert it?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproduceable code example in the question itself. If you are using Android, then you are using opengl-es, not opengl and you should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Just use the standard library to read the data from the files and store them in a string. That has nothing to do with OpenGL, it is just about how familiar you are with the C standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do it the same way that you'd load any other file:

```
char * get_file_contents(char const* file_name) {
    FILE * file = fopen("vert.glsl", "r");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    char * str = malloc(size);
    fread(str, 1, size, file);
    fclose(file);
    return str;
}

int main() {
    /*...*/
    char const* vShaderStr = get_file_contents("vert.glsl");
    char const* fShaderStr = get_file_contents("frag.glsl");
    userData->programObject = esLoadProgram ( vShaderStr, fShaderStr );
    free(vShaderStr);
    free(fShaderStr);
    /*...*/
}
```

I only program in C++, so I'm not going to try to add error handling to this code. This should be enough for you to get a start, though.